Visual studio code Python typing issue with relative import
Im not really well versed with python just learning langchain over the weekend but I've hit this nuance, this isn't entirely a core python question, but this is the most appropriately channel I've found.
So when following along on collab imports would work fine like this
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS 
But visual studio code (Pylance lang server) seems to not like that, it gets the type of Any.
VS code problem screenshot
To satisfy it I have to import the following way.
from langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS 
VS code screenshot
However the former approach runs just fine.
Im wondering if there is a setting or something im missing to be able to do "relative" imports in the former manner which is the style pre-dominantly used in the langchain docs.

Looking at the source code, we can see that FAISS is made available to langchain_community.vectorstores dynamically by overriding __getattr__ for the module object using a lookup table of module and class names as strings, where no type information is available, and which is consequently annotated as returning Any.
(It could be annotated with a typing.Protocol or abc.ABC return type which describes the common interface of all the vectorstores implementations.)
So you have no other choice as to import from langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss explicitly.

Oh good grief! that would definitely explain it.

I guess, they don't want to unnecessarily import submodules unless they are asked for, they could probably use an if TYPE_CHECKING: block to just import all those names
